# tabularx and csvreader putting everything in the last column with one row

Tags: tabularx, columns, width, csv, csvsimple

This is the same problem I ran into from the previous question, I finally narrowed it down to some line break problem. I found several line of code, that suppose to work and tried it on with my Texmaker and MikTeX, but it doesn't. Every line except the first line was squished into the last column of 1st row.

Weird enough, it works fine on my colleague's computer, which I believe is the older version of MiKTeX.

I tried to put `\\` after the last column `& \csvcoliv`, it finally recognized the linebreak, but it also produce an extra line in the table, which I don't want. Anyone know the reason?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mycsv.csv}
This,is,my,example
Red,Green,This is some very very long text,This is also some very very long text
Blue,Yellow,This is some even longer text without real content,This is also some even longer text without real content
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,letterpaper, openleft, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,csvsimple,longtable,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llXX}\toprule
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}\\\midrule
\csvreader[late after line=\\\midrule,late after last line=\\\bottomrule]
  {mycsv.csv}
  {}
  {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This is my output:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: it feels like, the csvreader doesn't recognize the comma in csv file anymore, after the 1st line

Comment: update, I tried to play with the csv file, with only two lines in csv, the table will put the entire second line into the last column of 1st row. Once there is a 3rd or more lines in csv file, it starts  to give "!missing number"  and "illegal unit of measure" alternate compile errors.  hopefully provide some idea.

Comment: The issue you've encountered appears to have gotten fixed in version 1.22 (date: 2021/06/07) of the `csvsimple` package.

Comment: Thanks Mico, I tried to manually install the 1.22 version of csvsimple, the problem didn't go.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use MikTeX's own utilities to update the TeX distribution in a more automated (and more bullet-proof) way?  I use TeXLive2021; I performed a `sudo tlmgr --update --all` run this morning and got version 1.22 of `csvsimple` as a result. With the latest version of `csvsimple` installed, the problem behavior you describe in your query no longer surfaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mico. Yes, I have been using MikTex Console, but the automatic update only keep the CSVsimple to 1.21, I don't know why.  tried uninstall - reinstall-update the specific package, still 1.21, will try with texlive today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved, big thanks to Mico. The reason is, outdated MikTex's package database and it only update the csvsimple to 1.21 version, which was published back in 2019. I uninstalled the csvsimple package, and downloaded the 1.22 version from CTAN, manually put the whole csvsimple folder in both, MikTex\Tex\Latex, and MikTex\Doc\Latex\ . It finally works. (tried to follow the readme and replace a few files to install, but it didn't work, you have to uninstall first and replace/paste the whole folder of csvsimple in both places.  It took me 4.5 days, I am so happy right now, thanks again, Mico, for pointing out the root cause.